# HBASE: update the existing java object containing list via JAVA API

Tags: java, hbase

Say I have a class A as below:

class A{

List <String> ids;

}

Initially I store two id's in the list say '1'&'2',later based on some requirement I delete one Id from the list, assume I  deleted '2'. Then I  update the object by deleting id '2' from the list and persist the same in HBASE. But I see id '1' getting duplicated in Hbase after the update operation and id '2' is deleted. Any Idea why it is happening?

Comment: Share your table schema and the queries as well.

Comment: Sorry I cannot share because it is company's proprietary software

Comment: If you have any suggestions please give I will try

Comment: How can one help without relevant info.. voting to close this.

Answer (score 0):

In described case, Row Id must be the same for every `Put` operation you perform. `new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowId));`
It sounds like you have auto-generated (or salted id), so every time you perform `Put` it creates new record instead of updating existing one.